# Generate ids for a database based on certain information

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I need a way to generate ids for a database based on certain information. Depending on the conference the user is registering for, the id will differ. The id will be 4 digits of the event identifier concatenated with 5 sequential digits.  For example:

Event A: 1000

Event B: 2000

Event C: 3000

An id for event A could be 100012345, and the next number for this id would be 100012346. An id for event B could be 200012345. Etc.

1. So how can I grab the last id for a certain event?
2. How can I autogenerate the next number for this?

Comment: are you gonna hire a developer from here

Comment: @un-lucky Hm? I am coding it, but I am not sure how to pull the last id from a database with specific criteria.

Comment: why not have auto generated id's and then have this value as some form of reference. The easiest way to then handle this "incrementing/auto generating" registration codes will be have  a look up table for your events and then the next available id to it. eg `event a` 1000 `next code`12345

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952021/different-ways-to-generate-the-latest-int-type-primary-foreign-key-in-code/17952131#17952131

Answer (score 1):

Use `uniqueidentifier` type for IDs with newid() default value , not int. This will create automatically new id of type guid.

If the problem is to take last created ID.Create two new columns in your table `UpdateDate` and `CreateDate`. When you are inserting a record

```
CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
```

On update

```
UpdateDate = DateTime.Now;
```

If you want to take last create item you will fetch data from database with this query:

```
Select * from [TableName] Order By CreateDate Desc
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you split the `event` and `id` as two separate columns in the DB and make them both primary key.

Then, should you need to add another key, first check what `event` you need (for example 1000) then check on DB what's the max `id` for that event. This should answer your first question.

As for your second question, once you have the max `id` for the event, you can just add +1.

Or even better, you could define `id` as auto-increment, but I'm not sure it'll work on a single part of a complex primary key.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on combining the two int values as a string then you would have to search. Since you are using strings you will need to make sure your sequence number is zero padded e.g 200000001 being the first id for event B.  Given this then the query

```
Select top 1 ID from [TableName] Where ID like '2000%' Order By ID Desc
```

should get you the largest ID and you will have to break it apart/convert to int and increment it. Of course you will then need some collision handling code when you attempt to create the record unless you are single thread/process when changing the db.

You might want to consider breaking these two concepts apart. You could use individual int fields to prevent doing string searches and instead combine the two int values when you need to present them as a combined identifier. Then you r SQL is

```
Select Top 1 SequenceId from [TableName] Where EventId=2000 Order By SequenceId Desc
```

Also if you truly want auto incremented sequence identifiers then you would have to move to a table per event with an auto incremented PK on each table as primary keys are the only auto incremented fields in SQL Server.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, a trigger would be a good bet. You could create an sql trigger which would fire before the insert, checking which event the user is registering for, and generating the corresponding Id.

Comment: There generally is no reason to use a trigger when that action can simply be written in the business logic, ie: stored procedure (preferably) or client code.